# Multi Byte Shifting

Tags: bit-shift

I am working to shift an array of bytes.
I want to shift three bytes to left.
Let's say I have `00000001 10000000 00000101 11111011`.
What I want to do is, to move the last three bytes, so that, I could get a result like `10000000 00000101 11111011 00000000`.
I tried this method

```
data[0]=(byte)((data[1]+data[2]+data[3])<<8)
```

but didn't get the right result.

Would anyone help me do multi byte shifting?

Comment: wouldnt data[1]+data[2]+data[3] be a single byte entity if data[] is a byte array? shouldnt that be `data[1]<<16 | data[2] << 8 | data[3]` instead? otherwise please explain what the data[] is and how it represents your input.

Comment: You're right. data...[1], [2] and [3] are just one representing a numeric value. data[0] contains a numeric value and the next three does the same but second numeric value is stored in 3 bytes.

Comment: what i am trying to do here is to clear the first byte and move the next three bytes so that i could get the value by using the BitConverter and get a UInt32

Comment: I am trying to parse a DIAMETER header with 20 bytes and there are values store in just one byte so I need to get the values of the single byte and three bytes that I cannot just use the BitConverter and automatically assign to an Int since that will get four bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Without a language I can't really give code but why not just shift the elements in the array? Just set data[0] = data[1], data[1] = data[2], etc... and then zero fill the last element

Comment: I need to implement it via shifting so that it will not be that hard coded...so I'm trying to find the fastest way. Thanks!

Comment: Please see my comments on Jean-Bernard's.

Comment: I am trying to parse a DIAMETER header with 20 bytes and there are values store in just one byte so I need to get the values of the single byte and three bytes that I cannot just use the BitConverter and automatically assign to an Int since that will get four bytes.

Comment: C# supports byte[] so why not use that and do what I said before?

Comment: That could be but I am instructed to use shifting...I couldn't get any workaround. I tried other things but didn't work. Do you have any idea on parsing a Diameter header?

Comment: Is this for an assignment as I see that as an arbitrary restriction?

Comment: Then I don't see why you can't use a byte array and just shift the elements, if you're reading from a socket it returns a byte array to begin with...